# Tensorflow: How to get a right prediction?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I load my model which already be saved before , and input a picture to get its prediction of class , but no matter what picture I input , I still get same prediction ,I don't know why and how to solve . The test of model is ok . Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import re
import os
import cg


checkpoint='/home/vrview/tensorflow/example/char/tfrecords/try1/cg_try/'
img_dir='/home/vrview/tensorflow/example/char/test_abc/5093.jpg'
MODEL_SAVE_PATH = "/home/vrview/tensorflow/example/char/tfrecords/try1/cg_try/"

def get_one_image():
    image = Image.open(img_dir)    
    image = image.resize([56, 56])
    image = np.array(image)
    return image

def evaluate():
    image_array = get_one_image()
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        image = tf.cast(image_array, tf.float32)
        image_1 = tf.image.per_image_standardization(image) 
        image_2 = tf.reshape(image_1, [1, 56, 56, 3])

        logit = cg.inference(image_2, evaluate, None)
        y = tf.nn.softmax(logit)    
        x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[56, 56, 3])
        saver = tf.train.Saver()

        with tf.Session() as sess:
          ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(MODEL_SAVE_PATH)
          if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
               global_step = ckpt.model_checkpoint_path.split('/')[-1].split('-')[-1]
               saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
               print('Loading success, global_step is %s' % global_step)
               prediction = sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: image_array})
               max_index = np.argmax(prediction)
               print ('max_index=%d'%max_index)
          else:
               print('No checkpoint file found')

def main(argv=None):
    evaluate()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```

When I run debug, I get the prediction is [ 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 ,0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ] . my code is 10 classify, the input picture is 10 numbers and size is [56,56,3] . I get the max_index is 1 whatever the input is .  does anybody know anything about it? Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you get different predictions using a validation set? Does the prediction given match the input image? Can you post any input and output used for reference.

Comment: The prediction is still wrong , it doesn't much the image. the input image is number image just like image in mnist_data. But my image's channel is 3 . It is good with test data . Just now , I chance the net and use other model , it's prediction is right. So I confused, why the first model can't , but the second model can do it . Both model in test data is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `x = tf.placeholder ...` is not used by anything in TensorFlow. You declared a placeholder there and nothing else uses `x`!

Recall that TensorFlow is a computation graph, and when you call `sess.run` it executes the necessary operations and returns you the value. I don't understand what you're trying to do with `cg.inference`, but consider using `x` as the input to some TensorFlow operations and do most of what you need to do in TensorFlow.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the net . It can work when I change another net .thank you very much

Comment: Like what I mentioned above, you should really consider operating everything with `x` as your input to the graph and all TF operations using `x` or derivatives (not the calculus derivative), of `x`. I'm not entirely sure why you would call `cg.inference`.

Comment: e....cg.inference is just a inference net that return a logit . I use it for my input image to make convolution and compute softmax . The net I used in cg.inference is AlexNet. May be  some parameters is wrong that make me get wrong prediction . Actually I fill it is troublesome because every time I must use cg.inference . If I save model with .pb file ,may be is more simple . But I don't know how to do .